# I/O errors on MySQL Slave doing replication

Tags: mysql, io

Running: Centos 6.2 VM
Attached a 1Tb disk to it (called sdc1)

Installed MySQL on it to be a slave of a replication.

The MySQL data files are on the attached 1Tb disk.

The problem is: The slave is not keeping up with the master.

The "messages" file lists I/O errors (attached below).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Error is below:

```
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(6): 0a 02 a1 ff 08 00
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 21560
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: cmd 0xa scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x86
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: stor pkt ffff880086431e00 autosense data valid - len 18
storvsc: Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
storvsc: Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(6): 0a 02 a1 ff 08 00
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 21560
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x86
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: stor pkt ffff880086431e00 autosense data valid - len 18
storvsc: Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
storvsc: Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 0c e0 10 4f 00 00 08 00
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 27001346
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x86
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: stor pkt ffff880100c72980 autosense data valid - len 18
storvsc: Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
storvsc: Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 0f 2a 08 c7 00 00 10 00
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 31801617
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 31801618
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: cmd 0xa scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x86
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: stor pkt ffff8803f576b140 autosense data valid - len 18
storvsc: Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
storvsc: Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(6): 0a 02 a2 3f 08 00
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 21568
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: cmd 0xa scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x86
hv_storvsc vmbus_0_7: stor pkt ffff8800ab42e440 autosense data valid - len 18
storvsc: Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
storvsc: Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(6): 0a 02 a1 ff 08 00
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 21560
lost page write due to I/O error on sdc1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently run `fsck` on your disk to see if it can find and fix your errors?

Also, do you have a swap drive on the slave?

Comment: Running this now. why do you ask about swap drive on the slave?

Comment: I had a NetBSD box that would display I/O errors if I had a swap drive defined, but not loaded. Never understood it. Fixed it by moving to FreeBSD :P

Comment: That is very interesting. Thanks for the insight I have passed that lesson along to my team. Not sure if it applies here but it is definitely a good idea. Waiting on results of the fsck still.